# Jenkins fails to create Scratch Org

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, connected-apps, jenkins, jenkinsfile

I have a CI process runnning in Jenkins. The script is pushing everything to  the devHub org and creating a package version.
Next, it's trying to create a scratch org but is failing and throwing this message: **Oauth client secret of personal connected app**?

[image]

Any ideas why is it failing?

Command to create the scratch: sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a ${alias} --setdefaultusername --clientid ${CONNECTED_APP_CONSUMER_KEY} -w 10

Comment: Are you authorizing the devhub org using `sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant` before creating the scratch org. I am referring to the example https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ci_jenkins_code.htm when asking

Answer (score 0):

You need to be authorized to the DevHub org to create a scratch org, following the instructions here
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_jwt_flow.htm

Then, create your scratch org like you try in your screenshot, it should work.

I strongly suggest to use more advanced scripts ( reading sfdx outputs and reusing them in the next commands), like in the [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ci_jenkins_code.htm) provided by Zack Walter

Don't hesitate to create a [Jenkins Shared](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) Library to reuse SFDX commands , avoid too many copy-paste and be able to use [Declarative Pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline) instead of the scripted pipeline of the example.